# python: re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', string) for a list

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have a list of strings such as

```
list1 = [['Hey There'],['Good Afternoon'],['How is your day']]
```

how can I use this code

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', string).lower()
```

to go through all the strings at once instead of doing each individually. Can I do a loop?

at the end, end up with something like

```
list1 = [['hey there'],['good afternoon'],['how is your day']]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "all the strings at once"? And what is the desired result?

Comment: so it works if I do this `re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', text[1]).lower()`  because it is doing it for just one string of the list. But what if I have a list of 99 strings, I would not want to do each individually, it there a way to do all the strings like a loop.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Your only non-letters are spaces already, so your `re.sub` seems pointless...

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [[re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', string).lower()]
         for string, in list1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7BDoIwDIbve4reBgmQGC9eOPgaLjNBKWwJrks3gvPlJ0FMPNtDD9@f/2t9iobc8eQ5Z/vwxBEYhZhsiAdoQSlpMEE0yCh1peRI1EM3RGRH5DZkaAEbINHM0HdJai3w6fEe/@//3GdswnwrpLqe60tXv7SsQMK6QmTrxrKZaEEuSi3gOwPxnlZgHWyu1elXEovd3MLnxzLnNw)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it individually, one way or the other, because `re.sub` expects `string` to be a `str` or `bytes`.

Assuming each nested list only has 1 string:

```py
import re

nested_list_of_string = [['Hey There'], ['Good Afternoon'], ['How Is Your Day']]

def lower_string_in_nested_list(list_):
    function = lambda list_: re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', ' ', list_[0]).lower()
    return [*map(function, list_)]

print(lower_string_in_nested_list(nested_list_of_string))
```

Output:

```
['hey there', 'good afternoon', 'how is your day']
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) applies a function to every item in `list_`. In this case, the function just grabs the first (and only) item from `list_`, which is the string you want to lower, and calls `re.sub`.

Comment: I'd say the `map(lambda` anti-pattern doesn't really get any better if you hide it behind the assign-lambda-to-name anti-pattern.